# ¿Cómo llamar todas las urls de una página?

Tags: javascript, url

Tengo los siguientes enlaces, pero quiero incluir todos en uno solo.

```
<script>
 var url=window.location;

  if(url =='https://dominio.com/inicio' || url =='https://dominio.com/nosotros' || url =='https://dominio.com/etc'){
    alert('mostrar algo');    
            }
    else{
     if(url =='https://dominio.com/en/inicio' || url =='https://dominio.com/en/nosotros' || url =='https://dominio.com/en/etc'){
    alert('mostrar algo');    
            }
    }
</script>
```

Hacer algo como eldominio.com/**todosloslinks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es para diferenciar idiomas sólo tienes que preguntar si la variable URL contiene la parte específica que diferencia el idioma.

```
if (url.includes("/en/")) {
 alert("inglés");
} else {
 alert("otro");
}
```

Comment: Excelente, Muchas gracias!